# Debugger for XQuery that uses Saxon

Tags: eclipse, debugging, xquery, saxon

Can anyone suggest a debugger for XQuery? I would prefer one that is either online or works within Eclipse, and I prefer something that uses Saxon. So far, all I've found is XQDT (which has little documentation and does not work with Saxon) and a few stand-alone commercial apps.

All I want to do is understand why my XQuery isn't selecting the elements I think it should. (My requirement for Saxon is because I've had bad experiences with these processors not meeting the same standard.)

Any suggestions? How are others testing their queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently XQDT supports only execution (no debugging) with the Saxon XQuery processor.

The only debuggers build so far in XQDT are for:

- Zorba XQuery processor:
  http://www.zorba-xquery.com/
- Sausalito XQuery Web application
  framework: http://www.28msec.com/

You can have our latest version from:

- the Eclipse update site: http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/incubator/repository/xquery/milestones/ (updated every 6 weeks)
- or downloading the already packaged "Sausalito Tools": http://www.28msec.com/download/download_sausalito (updated every 2 weeks)

Gabriel,
XQDT Committer

Answer (score 2):

**[oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xquery_debugger.html) offers a XQuery debugger** that can be used both with SaxonEE and with MarkLogic XML database:

**http://www.oxygenxml.com/xquery_debugger.html**

Comment: +1 for oXygen. I especially like the linked output results and the profiler.

Answer (score 1):

No Saxon, but I was able to get Eclipse and XQDT to work with the debugger. Just getting going though, so there could still be some lurking issues.
http://richmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/02/debug-xquery-in-eclipse-configuration.html

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.