# Using XQDT + Zorba to debug OSB Xqueries

Tags: xquery, zorba

I am trying to debug some xqueries written for Oracle Service Bus, using various tools like XmlSpy, Eclipse XQDT with zorba etc.. 
They all fail because of a BEA specific xquery function "group" which is probably the equivalent of the xquery function "group by" in xquery 3.0.
So the xquery engines I am using dont recognize it, and therefore I cant do any step-by-step debugging.
Assuming I have all the *.jar files from (BEA) Oracle that implement these xquery functions, does anyone know if it's possible to import them in zorba or XMLSPY so that these vendor specific functions are recognized?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugger for XQuery that uses Saxon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720866/debugger-for-xquery-that-uses-saxon)